How to fine-tune a non-OpenAI LLM for a multi-turn conversation, are there any examples?
maybe someone did this already and knows an example for:

Fine-tune a non-OpenAI LLM for a multi-turn conversation
Example data
Training / Testing format

Thanks,
Thomas
